# How to save a file in different package folder than current package folder

Tags: java, spring, file, maven, classloader

I have a maven project structure like following.

Structure

```
src\main\java
  - app.mycompany.myapp.core
  - app.mycompany.myapp.core.abc
  - com.mycompany.myapp.core.generated
```

Now from one java file located in `core.abc` I want to create files under `core.generated` . How can i get directory reference to `core.generated` in a java file located in `core.abc`.

Comment: Can you add some code which do the file saving part?

Comment: Actaully I have a string object. I just need to create a file under 'core.generated' and dump the string in that file. But not sure how to get a reference to the directory core.generated. Any ideas?

Comment: When do you want to generate the files? During build time? Then you need a maven plugin or execute your generator class with the maven exec plugin. In that case you just create a file reference with the directory structure of the package (packages are just plain directories).

Comment: No i want to generate classes from another java class.